Prevent modification of original list after placing it in a closure in Kotlin
I don't know closures in Kotlin so I want to understand this aspect. I have a class Foo that holds a list bar, technically immutable. But if I need to change it I create a new list and replace the value of the class member Foo.bar.
Then I create a Unit that will loop through that list, so I send Foo.bar as a closure, but it processes over a long time (with "sleeps" in between), therefore there is plenty of time for the contents of Foo.bar to change.
How do I ensure the traversal goes without changes (print 1 to 10), is the closure ensuring that already? do I need to make a copy of the list (element by element not just a reference to the list) before sending it to the closure?
class Foo(var bar: List<Int>)

suspend fun <T> Collection<T>.traverseOverTime(block: (T) -> Unit) {
    this.iterator().traverseOverTime(block)
}

suspend fun <T> Iterator<T>.traverseOverTime(block: (T) -> Unit) {
    repeat(2) {
        if (!hasNext()) return
        block(next())
    }

    delay(1000)
    traverseOverTime(block)
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val foo = Foo(listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

    launch {
        foo.bar.traverseOverTime { println(it.toString()) }
    }

    // case 1.: I hear this changes the list element regardless of immutable status
    delay(500)
    try {
        (foo.bar as MutableList<Int>)[2] = 1000
        println("case 1.: ${foo.bar}")
    } catch (e: Exception) { println("case 1.: $e") }

    // case 2.: so would this
    delay(1000)
    try {
        (foo.bar as MutableList<Int>).removeAt(3)
        println("case 2.: ${foo.bar}")
    } catch (e: Exception) { println("case 2.: $e") }

    // case 3.: and this fully changes foo.bar
    delay(1000)
    foo.bar = listOf(100)
    println("case 3.: ${foo.bar}")
}

This outputs the following:
0
1
case 1.: [0, 1, 1000, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
1000
3
case 2.: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
4
5
case 3.: [100]
6
7
8
9
10


In this particular case, traverseOverTime will definitely complete before any of the 1, 2, 3 are executed. In a multi-threaded environment, you can use a lock or synchronized to ensure this.


is "protected" by the base classes (ArrayList in my particular case) having a "modificationCount" that is increased on remove, and crashes the iterator on next() which checks for the count to be zero and stay at that



was not protected at all



happened but was ineffective at modifying the prints, which means the closure makes a copy of the reference value, and doesnt hold a pointer to the reference (foo.bar@123->List@120, closure@124->List@120), not (closure@124->foo.bar@123)


Is that your answer to your own question? While some of the things you say is true, it is irrelevant to the code presented. Concurrent modification is not possible with this code, because all the modifications to bar will be executed after traverseOverTime returns.

too pedantic, theres a wait in there that should be enough to understand intent


is protected even with mutable lists and mutable iterators, as the base arraylist iterator is the one checking for concurrent modifications


I understand your "intent" (if I didn't, I would have also mentioned that casting emptyList() to a MutableList will fail), but the answer of your question depends on how you implement this "wait". If you just use Thread.sleep, then just see my first comment. If you run traverseOverTime in a different thread, then not even 2 is completely protected. You should use a lock. If you start a coroutine to wait, the answer would probably also be different depending on the coroutine scope/the dispatcher your use (though I am not too familiar with coroutines).

The way you wrote //wait(1000) suggests that this is more likely the first case, than the latter two cases. You should [edit] your question to clarify your question.

The question is pretty unclear. The only closure in the code doesn't really use the list itself. Also, list is modified after it completed iterating already. Generally speaking: yes, we shouldn't modify the list while iterating it. And yes, closures create copies of references, but it all depends on a specific case and you didn't provide any.

feel free to improve the question, it's hard to get it perfect when ignorant, thanks

I streamlined the code of your question and made it executable. Please verify that this does what you had in mind. Also, please update the text part of your question to be more clear about what you want to ask.

@Leviathan I can try answering this, but if you already started, then I'll skip. Your answers don't need improvements ;-)

That's nice of you. :) But please feel free to write an answer, I won't interfere. Just wanted to provide a solid base for discussions. I deliberately kept my edit unbiased.

that looks like what I wanted yes, thank you

It is not that easy to answer the question as it touches multiple topics. Also, I won't discuss the specific examples in the question, I'll rather speak about concurrent modification in general. I'll focus on 4 subtopics:

Modify a reference to a collection vs modify contents of a collection.
Modify a collection and iterate over it concurrently.
Closures.
Ways to fix the problem.

1. Modify a reference to a collection vs modify contents of a collection.
First of all, we need to understand there is a huge difference between:
foo.bar = listOf(100)

And:
foo.bar[2] = 1000
foo.bar.removeAt(3)

First example updates the foo object by replacing a reference to a list into a reference to an entirely different list. There are two lists and we switch between them. Second example modifies the contents of an existing list stored in foo.bar. First example modifies the foo and doesn't change contents of any lists. Second example doesn't modify the foo, but modifies contents of a list.
2. Modify a collection and iterate over it concurrently.
This difference is important, because if we for example started iterating over foo.bar, no matter if using foo.bar.forEach or for (x in foo.bar), then changing foo.bar to another list doesn't affect us at all. We already iterate over the list, we keep a reference to it, and we don't observe the foo.bar property anymore.
It is much different if we modify the list contents from another thread, while we iterate over it. This is generally a not good idea, in most cases we will get the ConcurrentModificationException exception.
3. Closures.
As a general rule, closures store copies of references. But this is still more complicated than it sounds and we could have many different scenarios here. For example:
launch {
    foo.bar.forEach { ... }
}

It stores a reference to foo. When the lambda is executed, it acquires its bar from foo and starts iterating it. If we first create the lambda, then we replace foo.bar with another list and then we execute the lambda, it will see the new list.
val bar = foo.bar
launch {
    bar.forEach { ... }
}

This is different. The lambda stores a reference to bar directly, so if we modify the list stored in foo.bar, it will still use the old one. This example may seem pretty "artificial", but imagine you have any kind of utility function which accepts a list and we pass foo.bar to it - it doesn't even know about the foo, it knows the current value of foo.bar only.
var bar = foo.bar
launch {
    bar.forEach { ... }
}
bar = listOf(100)

It stores a reference to bar, but bar is mutable and the closure will see we replaced it with entirely different list.
foo.bar.forEach {
    println(it)
}

This example references the first version of the question, where it discussed closures, but the only closure was like the above. In this case the closure doesn't know anything about the list itself. It only receives subsequent items and this is the only thing it knows about.
4. Ways to fix the problem.
Generally speaking, problem of modifying a list contents and a reference to a list are rather orthogonal. If we already started iterating over a collection, it doesn't matter we will modify its reference. Modifying its contents will crash. On the other hand, closures care about references, but they don't really care about list contents. What matters is the point in time when we start iterating - this is when we "stick" to a specific collection.
There is no simple answer to how to fix the problem of closure observing different collection than we needed. It really depends on a specific case. I hope examples from above already explained how closures observe references and how to use them to observe exactly we need.
There are multiple possible ways to fix the problem of modifying the collection we iterate over. Again, it depends on a specific case. We can use mutexes / synchronized blocks to disallow concurrent access to collections. We can create a copy before starting iterating, but that also requires a mutex, because creating a copy is itself iterating, so we can't modify while copying.
Another solution, which is encouraged in languages like Kotlin, is to prefer immutable/read-only collections over mutable ones. Instead of modifying the list in-place, we can assume the list itself is not mutable. To modify it, we actually create its copy (this is safe, because nobody can modify it while we copy it), then we apply some modifications and replace the foo.bar entirely. This way we can iterate over the list at any time and this is safe. Remember that when we replace foo.bar, all existing iterating/copying operations will still use the old list, so we won't interfere with them. One caveat is that if we run 2 modification operations concurrently and the second one should see results of the first one, we still need some kind of synchronization.

Honestly, I don't know if this answers the question, but it was not really easy to me to answer it. It is a pretty wide topic and we can approach it from multiple angles.

launch { foo.bar.forEach { ... } } 

It stores a reference to foo. When the lambda is executed, it acquires its bar from foo and starts -- Am I correct theres two closures there, and foo.bar assignments will affect forEach if it hasnt started yet, but once it does only changes to bar elements (whatever it was at the time forEach captured bar reference) will affect it?


Yes, this is correct. foo.bar is not captured by the inner closure if this is what you mean. Inner closure doesn't at all reference foo or bar. forEach is called on the foo.bar, so the list is stored on the stack. Lambda itself knows nothing about the list - it is called passing individual items to it.
